# how to add restrictions in login form?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i'm creating a login form for my system and want to add a User and Admin account. what i did in my database is to create a table for my users with a specific user type U_Type would be either 1 = admin or 2 = user.

i want to add an if statement that would call my column name U_Type and compare it either 1 or 2. below is my unfinished code. i'm using visual studio 2008 c# and ms sql 2005

here is my code:

```
float Outcome;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MJ-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Users;Integrated Security=True";
    conn.Open();

    String txtUser = textBox1.Text;
    String txtPass = textBox2.Text;

    string query = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE U_Name=@U_Name AND U_Pass=@U_Pass AND U_Type=@type";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@U_Name", txtUser));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@U_Pass", txtPass));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@type", type));

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
        Outcome = Convert.ToInt32(lblOutcome.Text);
        Outcome = Outcome - 1;
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();

        lblOutcome.Text = Outcome.ToString();
        if (Outcome == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have reached the maximum number of trial");
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    else if (textBox2.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
        Outcome = Convert.ToInt32(lblOutcome.Text);
        Outcome = Outcome - 1;
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();

        lblOutcome.Text = Outcome.ToString();
        if (Outcome == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have reached the maximum number of trial");
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    else if (dr.HasRows == true)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MJ-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Users;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT U_Name ='"+textBox1.Text+"', U_Pass = '" +textBox2.Text+"', U_Type = 1 FROM tblUsers",con);


        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();


        if ()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
            MDIParent1 settingsForm = new MDIParent1();
            settingsForm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
            MDIParent2 settingsForm = new MDIParent2();
            settingsForm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }


        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
            Outcome = Convert.ToInt32(lblOutcome.Text);
            Outcome = Outcome - 1;
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox2.Clear();

            lblOutcome.Text = Outcome.ToString();
            if (Outcome == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have reached the maximum number of trial");
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

i want the if statement to be here

```
  else if (dr.HasRows == true)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MJ-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Users;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT U_Name ='"+textBox1.Text+"', U_Pass = '" +textBox2.Text+"', U_Type = 1 FROM tblUsers",con);


            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();


            if ("@type"==1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
                MDIParent1 settingsForm = new MDIParent1();
                settingsForm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
                MDIParent2 settingsForm = new MDIParent2();
                settingsForm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
```

i really don't know the proper syntax for it. help me please i would really appreciate it. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have, roughly, the right idea, but your implementation is off.

You're validating the text boxes after you send the SQL query but before you check the results, and you're also passing in the type of the user.

The user type should be stored in the database along with the user, and you can return the type of user for the matching row (based on username and password).  And your syntax is way off in some places.

A simplified approach based on what you appear to be doing would be something like this:

Do validation on the text boxes *before* executing the command.  If validation passes, then select the row that matches the user name and password, and process the results accordingly:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    bool validInput = false;

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(textBox1.Text))
    {
        validInput = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a user name.");
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(textBox2.Text))
    {
        validInput = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a password.");
    }

    if (validInput)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MJ-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Users;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE U_Name = @U_Name AND U_Pass = @U_Pass", conn);
            command.Parameters.Add("@U_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@U_Pass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    string userType = reader["U_type"].ToString();
                    if (userType == "1")
                    {
                        // Handle regular users
                    }
                    else if (userType == "2")
                    {
                        // Handle admin users
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login failed.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code illustrates the approach.  If both text boxes have text in them, the `validInput` flag is set to `true`.  The connection is then opened, the command and parameters are set, the command is executed and a reader returned.  If the reader has rows (meaning 1 or more records that matched the username and password are found), the `reader` is advanced to the first record (there should be only one match for a given username/password combination).

The "U_type" column is interrogated to see if it's a regular user or an admin user, and the user is processed accordingly.

It's not clear from your posted code whether "U_type" is a string or an integer; if it's an integer you'll need to convert it like this:

```
int userType = Convert.ToInt32(reader["U_type"]);
```

And change the corresponding if checks:

```
if (userType == 1)
```

and

```
if (userType == 2)
```

Comment: it's an int. thanks for helping, i'll try this code right away

Answer (score 1):

If you want to authenticate user and compare the Type then return DataTable.

```
 public DataTable ValidateUser(string username,string password)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd; SqlDataReader dr;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString);
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from tblUsers where U_Name=@U_Name and U_Pass=@U_Pass";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@U_Name", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@U_Pass", password);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(dr);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dt = null;

        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Close(); con.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Calling ValidateUser Method:

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt=ValidateUser();
if(dt!=null && dt.Rows.Count>0)
{
    if(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.[0]["U_Type"])==1)
    {
       //show form for user where utpe=1
    }
    else if(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.[0]["U_Type"])==2)
   {
       //show form for user where utype=1
    }
    else
    {
       //otherstuff
    }
}
else
{
 //invwalid user
}
```

hopethis helps

Comment: what is that ConnectionStringBiz??

Comment: This is a workable solution, but IMO a `DataTable` is overkill.  Just stick with the `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: @Mark ConnectionStringBiz is a userdefined Static Class where connectionString is assigned from web.config file. You can add your own connectionstring here...for your simplicity i have modified plz check the posted answer...